# refresh page after last appended iframe is loaded

Tags: javascript, iframe

I created a simple bookmarklet to append 3 invisible iframe's to the current document looking like this:

```
javascript: (function() {

var link = window.location.href;
var desktop = link.replace(".com", ".com/purge");;
var mobile = link.replace(".com", ".com/mpurge");
var tablet = link.replace(".com", ".com/tpurge");
var platforms = [desktop,tablet,mobile];

for (i = 0;i<platforms.length; i++){
   ifrm = document.createElement("IFRAME"); 
   ifrm.setAttribute("src", platforms[i]); 
   ifrm.style.width = 0+"px"; 
   ifrm.style.height = 0+"px"; 
   document.body.appendChild(ifrm); 
   if(i==platforms.length-1){
        ifrm.onload = function(){
            location.reload();
        }
      }
   }

})();
```

what i want to do its to refresh the page im at after the third iframe is loaded but for some reason i cant get this one to work, any idea why?
thx!

Comment: Wouldn't this result in a an infinite loop of the page reloading?

Answer (score 0):

`i` will never be `== platforms.length` inside of loop, because your loop condition is `i<platforms.length`.

Make it `i == platforms.length - 1` or take reloading outside of the loop